# Exception while running ibtool: *** Collection was mutated while being enumerated. macOS

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, storyboard, xcode9

I am working on a macOS project. I have a NSCollectionView in it and it was working fine. later I changed the deployment target from 10.13 to 10.11. And now it give me this error when I build it.

[image]

I have tried removing and putting the NSCollectionView from Storyboard, but still no luck.

Comment: Just create a copy of collection which you are enumerating and use it in for iterating loop.

Comment: @VinitIngale  What? This is not in our code. This seems to be an XCode bug, but we need a workaround

Answer (score 0):

Select the xib file, modify the options in the Interface Builder Document
The above 10.9 system already does not support simulator below ios6